# ng-model does not bind within ng-repeat, while everything else does

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, ng-bind

I know there are a ton of questions already on this topic, I tried the solutions I found but it doesnt seem to work.
Basically I have this directive called basicMunch that goes through an array of objects and creates some html.
Everything works nicely and bind other than the ng-modal
Here is the code for the directive:

```
>     munches.directive('basicmunches', function() {   return {
>     require: 'ngModel',
>     template:`<div class='columns'>  <div ng-repeat="mu in basicMunches" class="card column col-4 col-sm-12">
>           <div class="card-header">
>             <h4 class="card-title">{{mu.name}}</h4>
>             <h6 class="card-subtitle">{{mu.type}}</h6>
>           </div>
>           <div class="card-body">
>             {{mu.text}}
>           </div>
>           <div class="card-footer">
>             <div class="form-group">
>               <label class="form-switch">
>                 <input ng-model="mu.tag" name="{{mu.tag}}"  type="checkbox" />
>                 <i class="form-icon"></i> Turn On
>               </label>
>             </div>
>           </div>
>         </div></div>`   } });
```

Here is the array:

```
 $scope.basicMunches  = [
    {"name":"The New York TImes",
     "text":"Get the top headlines from the NYT every morning", 
     "type":"News", "tag":"nyt"
    },
    {"name":"Wall Street Journal",
     "text":"Get the top headlines from the WSJ every morning", 
     "type":"News", "tag":"wsj"
    }
];
```

Here is what i see in the console 
[image]

I have tried doing $parent.mu.tag and $parent.$parent.mu.tag, but that didnt work as it shouldnt have because it isnt nested in some other scope (atleast not that I know of)

I tried doing the name of the controller.mu.tag, that too doesnt work

I tried doing mu['tag'] and that doesnt work either

I tried using {{ and that doesnt work
I changed it to ng-bind={{mu.tag}} and that does work
It is weird to me that it works for ng-bind but it doesnt work for ng-model....
Anyhow, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your ng-model="mu.tag" is bound to a string and the input is type="checkbox" that wont work. Either change the type to text or bind to a bool.

Comment: It seems to be working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kh25SrZv8W2jjm2GskWk?p=preview) in plunker, can you please reproduce issue over here..

Comment: @PankajParkar yes that script is working, but it isnt really what I am trying to do. If you inspect element the input you will see that the issue that I am asking about is still there, the ng-model still says it is equal to "mu.tag" and not the name of the tag as I would like

Comment: What you are trying to do is odd.  You really want `ng-model="wsj"`, by reading the value `wsj` from the `mu.tag` property, yes?  While there *might* be ways to make that possible, it doesn't really make sense in terms of this array, since that would imply that you have a property on `$scope` called `wsj`, and how does that relate to the rest of `mu`, particularly since there can be multiple `mu` but only one `wsj` property?

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I want to do. Each mu tag with have a different property, wsj was just an example. @Claies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you are wanting is to bind the `ng-model` property to the **value** of `mu.tag`, rather than to `mu.tag` itself.

Due to the way that `ng-model` is parsed, you need to use a variation of the bracket syntax in order to make this possible.  The proper syntax here is `$parent[mu.tag]` which will look on the `$parent` object for the property named by the value of `mu.tag`.  The parent of the `ng-repeat` is `$scope`, so this ends up with the property on the correct object.

```
<input ng-model="$parent[mu.tag]" name="{{mu.tag}}"  type="checkbox" />
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RZNDa2XVUoZp1z7QeN46?p=preview

Comment: intesesting, this looks like it works, although when i check using inspect element it just shows "$parent[mu.tag]" ... I am going to play around a little more and see if it works...

Comment: the browser doesn't know the *actual* property you are bound to, because it is an evaluated property, where normally you are binding to the property directly.

Comment: Also, I don't normally recommend using `$parent`, because if anything changes the DOM hierarchy it can cause unexpected results.  However, in this instance, your only other choices are to make an object that can hold the properties or change to the Controller As syntax.  I actually recommend changing to Controller As for quite a few reasons, but that's a bit beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Wow, interesting. Anyhow thank you very much. Would you maybe point me to some resource on the controller as syntax?

Comment: this https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controlleras-view-syntax is overall a great read, but the portion I referred you to is specifically about Controller As.

Answer (score 1):

Have the checkbox inputs fill properties of an object with [property accessor bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
<fieldset ng-repeat="mu in munchies">
    <input ng-model="choices[mu.tag]" name="{{mu.tag}}"
             type="checkbox" />
      &nbsp;  Turn On
</fieldset>
```

## [The DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/NvfjCIUg9Drd5Oz6Lp7G?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope) {
  var vm = $scope;
  vm.choices = {};
  vm.munchies  = [
    {"name":"The New York TImes",
     "text":"Get the top headlines from the NYT every morning", 
     "type":"News", "tag":"nyt"
    },
    {"name":"Wall Street Journal",
     "text":"Get the top headlines from the WSJ every morning", 
     "type":"News", "tag":"wsj"
    }
  ];
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    Subscriptions {{choices | json}}
    <fieldset ng-repeat="mu in munchies">
      <h3>{{mu.name}}</h3>
      <p>{{mu.text}}</p>
      <input ng-model="choices[mu.tag]" name="{{mu.tag}}"
                 type="checkbox" />
          &nbsp;  Turn On
      <br/>Subscribed {{choices[mu.tag]}}
    </fieldset>
  </body>
```